# ruby regular expression for empty line

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a little issue with ruby expressions.
Ruby Version: 2.3.0

I have following String:

```
================ Certificate 0 ================
Serial Number: 039de8
Issuer: E=test-support@test.de, CN=test-CA, OU=testou, O=test GmbH, L=Ber
lin, S=Berlin, C=DE
 NotBefore: 08.01.2018 11:10
 NotAfter: 08.01.2019 11:10
Subject: C=DE, S=Berlin, L=Berlin, OU=Testou, O=test, CN=test-1.test.tc
Non-root Certificate
Template:
Cert Hash(sha1): ea 61 42 ad 80 eb b7 94 b0 fb 90 90 39 ce 44 6e a9 ee f4 1b
  Key Container = {DE49D597-C00C-4433-9619-506FD234FF81}
  Unique container name: 73ab698919e3dcc47cad8c7543f78ff0_ae268432-4b90-4c10-adf
e-8c743fdedffa
  Provider = Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Private key is NOT exportable
Encryption test passed

================ Certificate 1 ================
Serial Number: 0a4cd4
Issuer: E=test-support@bdr.de, CN=test-CA, OU=testou, O=test GmbH, L=Ber
lin, S=Berlin, C=DE
 NotBefore: 05.01.2018 10:07
 NotAfter: 05.01.2019 10:07
Subject: C=DE, S=Berlin, L=Berlin, OU=testou, O=test, CN=test-2.test.tc
Non-root Certificate
Template:
Cert Hash(sha1): b2 49 95 e1 5c 47 4a 75 5c 1a 68 59 eb 26 05 bc 43 43 0e e9
  Key Container = {A4F9D180-3391-4D9F-855A-6BD5457CF719}
  Unique container name: 2b06a7fd8659046a8520a72ee921f2e9_ae268432-4b90-4c10-adf
e-8c743fdedffa
  Provider = Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Private key is NOT exportable
Encryption test passed
CertUtil: -store command completed successfully.
```

String was generated with:

```
certutil -store MY
```

How can I get this output in an Array?
I want that all information from `Certificate 0` and `Certificate 1` into a 2-element array.

Sometimes I have just one certificate (`Certificate 0`), without 
`Certificate 1`. In this case, my array should have just one element.

What I need is the correct regular expression. I want a regular expression
from `================ Certificate 0 ================` till to the blank line.

For example:

```
cert_util_output = %x(certutil -store MY)
certificate_array = cert_util_output.scan(/the_regular_expression/).flatten
```

Sorry for my bad english :)

Anybody a idea?
Best regards
mobios

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
cert_util_output.split(/\n\n/)
```

This splits the string on empty lines.

Comment: Hello Robin, thanks for your answer it was very helpfull. My issue is solved.

Best regards mobios

Comment: @mobios In case it's not clear, this (perfectly good) answer is not using a regular expression. You don't *need* a regular expression for this.

Comment: Hello Tom,  if you have a better idea please let me know. How can i do this better? Regards mobios

Comment: I tried to get certificate Information wirth. "certutil.exe -view -restrict" but i get always a errormessage -> the System cannot find the file specified" Therefore i try to use regularexpressions with ruby.

Comment: @mobios I'm not suggesting a better idea; this answer is perfectly good. My point was that your question seems heavily focused on a "regex solution", when in actual fact this is *better* solved *without* a regex.

Comment: @mobios If you have any additional issues like this, please raise them as new questions in an appropriate place. (Possibly that belongs in [server fault](https://serverfault.com/)?) It's not advised to raise such unrelated questions within the comments.